# how do i display user avatar in profile

Tags: php, image, profile

I have an image link stored in a table, and I want it to appear next to user name in **twitter-like** timeline.  How do I get the image link from user table to be displayed?  Below is the code I have as part of a general function to format the post. The **`formatTweet`** function is pulling data from a posted content table, not the user table where the user's image link is stored.

---

```
function formatTweet($session_user_id = 'username', $post, $link = 'link',
 $category, $dt) {
    if(is_string($dt)) $dt=strtotime($dt);

    $post=htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($post));

    return'
    <li>
    <a href="/'.$username.'"><img class="avatar" src="" width="48" height="48" alt="avatar" /></a>
    <div class="tweetTxt">
    <strong><a href="/'.$session_user_id.'">'.$session_user_id.'</a></strong> '. preg_replace('/((?:http|https|ftp):\/\/(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?[^\s\"\']+)/i','<a href="$1" rel="nofollow" target="blank">$1</a>',$post).'</br>
    <div class="link"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank"><img src="img/PostQuote_timeline.jpg" alt="Source"></a></div>
    <div class="upgrade"><a href="#" target=""><img src="img/upgrade_20.png" alt="Upgrade"></a></div>
    <div class="downgrade"><a href="#" target=""><img src="img/downgrade_20.png" alt="Downgrade"></a></div>
    <div class="category">'.$category.'</div></br>
    <div class="date">'.relativeTime($dt).'</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>';

}
```

---

Comment: Put image source in img src

Comment: use a service like gravatar